# Alternative solutions to an array search in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, performance, database-design

I am not sure if my database design is good for this tricky case and I also ask for help how the query for this could look like.

I plan a query with the following table:

```
       search_array      | value | id 
  -----------------------+-------+----
   {XYa,YZb,WQb}         | b     |  1
   {XYa,YZb,WQb,RSc,QZa} | a     |  2
   {XYc,YZa}             | c     |  3
   {XYb}                 | a     |  4
   {RSa}                 | c     |  5
```

There are 5 main elements in the search_array: XY, YZ, WQ, RS, QZ and 3 Values: a, b, c that are concardinated to each element.
Each row has also one value: a, b or c.

My aim is to find all rows that fit to a specific row in this sense: At **first** it should be checked if they have any same main elements in their search_arrays (yellow marked in the example).

As example:
Row id 4 an row id 5 wouldnt match because XY != RS.
Row id 1, 2 and 3 would match two times because they have all XY and YZ.
Row id 1 and 2 would even match three times because they have also WQ in common.

And **second**: if there is a Main Element match it should be 'crosschecked' if the lowercase letters after the Main Elements fit to the value of the other row.

As example: The only match for Row id 1 in the table would be Row id 4 because they both search for XY and the low letters after the elements match each value of the two rows.
Another match would be ROW id 2 and 5 with RS and search c to value c and search a to value a (green and orange marked).

[image]

My idea was to cut the search_array elements in the query in two parts with the RIGHT and LEFT command for strings. But I dont know how to combine the subqueries for this search.

Or would be a complete other solution faster? Like splitting the search array into another table with the columns 'foregin key' to the maintable, 'main element' and 'searched_value'. I am not sure if this is the best solution because the program would all the time switch to the main table to find two rows out of 3 million rows to compare their searched_values to the values?

Thank you very much for your answers and your time!

Comment: Please show formatted text as text, not as images.  We can't copy and paste your example into something actually runnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to represent the data in a normalized fashion. I'll do it in a `WITH` clause, but it would be better to store the data in this fashion to begin with.

```
WITH unravel AS (
   SELECT t.id, t.value,
          substr(u.val, 1, 2) AS arr_main,
          substr(u.val, 3, 1) AS arr_val
   FROM mytable AS t
      CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(t.search_array) AS u(val)
)
SELECT a.id AS first_id,
       a.value AS first_value,
       b.id AS second_id,
       b.value AS second_value,
       a.arr_main AS main_element
FROM unravel AS a
   JOIN unravel AS b
      ON a.arr_main = b.arr_main
         AND a.arr_val = b.value
         AND b.arr_val = a.value;
```